# Issue in MetaKeyword,MetaDescription information in JSP using Java

Tags: java, html, jsp, utf-8

```
<meta name="description" content="${metaDescription}" />
```

In case the user is in the french culture, When I view the page source

```
<meta name="description" content="Trouvez des pneus fiables et s�curitaires pour votre auto, VUS ou camionnette. Canadian Tire offre un grand choix de pneus d'hiver, toute saison et performants"/>
```

In place of **?**, It should be **é**

I tried to put equivalent `UTF-8` code for é. I got the same `UTF-8` code in view page source.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates that you are looking at a UTF-8 encoded document using ASCII decoding. You might be missing he correct content type definition in your html file, try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

to the `<head>` in the HTML document.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried but not working. Any another solution? Thanks for your reply

Comment: This won't work. The `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">` is **ignored** when the page is served over HTTP with a `Content-Type` header. The meta tag will only be used when you save the page to local disk and open it from there by `file://`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JSP page encoding to the desired charset. Add the following to the top:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This will do two things:

1. It tells the server that it should treat the characters in JSP as UTF-8 by `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`.
2. It tells the browser that it should interpret the characters from the server as UTF-8 by `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8")`.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)